# How we expand trigonometric equation like $\cos(t)+\cos(\frac{t^3}{4\pi^2})$ to obtain terms $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ with the same argument $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am searching for a general way (gladly also with the tools Mathematica, Maple, Matlab or Maxima CAS or a combination of these) to expand trigonometric terms like $\cos(t)+\cos(\frac{t^3}{4\pi^2})$ such that I obtain a result consisting of $\sin$ and/or $\cos$ parts having one and the same argument. The mixture of arguments in $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms disallows me to perform substitutions such as $s=\sin(\ldots)$, $c=\cos(\ldots)$.

I tried "TrigExpand" in Mathematica, "convert(...,'sincos')" in Maple, "rewrite(...,'sincos')" in Matlab, which did not work consistently (only sometimes for simple cases). When there is a nice straight forward way to expand those terms with paper and pencil then I don't shy away from that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such expansion doesn't exists, since any expression depending only on $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ is periodic, but $\cos(t)+\cos(\frac{t^3}{4\pi^2})$ is not.